# Create setup file include MySQL database inside it

Tags: c#

I developed application form using C# and connected this application with a MySQL database like this

```
string Coonstring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=***;Charset=utf8";
string cmd = "select name from project.material ;";
MySqlConnection connectionDatabase = new MySqlConnection(Coonstring);
MySqlCommand cmddata = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connectionDatabase);
MySqlDataReader myreader;
```

When I try to build this app. and create setup file and get this setup file to another laptop error messagbox appear tell me missing MySQL host.

[image]

So what should I do ?

Comment: you are hardcoding the host in the connection string.

Comment: You are pointing to localhost for your MySQL server... is this installed on the target system?

Comment: Yes this my MYSQL server name that installed in my laptop

Comment: @user3525082, but the target machine **doesn't** have an instance installed at all **or** one with that name.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an application configuration file. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)
2. Add an entry for a connection string - this can now be changed when deployed. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. Change your code to use it (as shown below).
4. Set the connection string appropriately on the deployed system in the `*.exe.config` file.

---

```
string Coonstring = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["KeyValueYouSupplied"]
    .ConnectionString;
```

Comment: This is what i founded in App. config   ( <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration> )

Comment: @user3525082, so add the sections that are appropriate based off of the MSDN article I linked to.